# How can I have only one onChange for several inputs in reacthooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

in react.js i add a name attribute to each element For example:

```
   handleChange1(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        this.setState({[name]: value});
    }
    <input name="inputone" type="text" value={this.state.value1} onChange={this.handleChange1} />
```

But how do I do that in react-hook?
for example:

```
           <Input
                      name="FirstName"
                      onChange={onChangeFirstName}    
                    ></Input>
const onChangeFirstName = (event) => {
    setFirstName(event.target.value);
  };
```

In fact, my question is, if I have multiple inputs, how can I write a handleChange for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did ask similar question a month ago, about using hooks with multiple state, with one onChangeHandler using hooks:

```
const [name, setName] = useState({
  firstName: '',
  middleName: '',
  lastName: '',
})

const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
 const {name, value} = event.target;

 setName({
   ...name,
   [name]: value,
 })
}

return(
  <div>
    <input
     type="text"
     name="fistName"
     value={firstNmae}
     onChange={onChangeHandler}
    />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I think you need to post it as a different question about the FetchData method