# How to create controlled inputs with parameters and passing event object using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, controlled-component

I am trying to make a form and create controlled inputs, I've used before `window.event` but this is deprecated and I don't want to use it anymore althought if I use it the solution works as I excepted I am concerned for compatibility, but if I don't use it, I tried using syntheticEvent and it doesn't work, I tried 2 ways  I added the event using .bind() which doesn't work gives the error that can't access inputs,setInputs before initialization, and in the second using the SyntheticEvent (e)=>{changeHandler}
when I write the second letter it crashes with error cannot read property id of null, what is going on, is this possible to do with hooks or I should go with classes?

```
 const changeHandler = (inputs, setInputs, clone, event) => {
      const cloned = clone(inputs[event.target.id]);
      cloned.config.value=event.target.value;
      setInputs(prevState=>{
          return {
              ...prevState,
              [event.target.id]:cloned
          }
      })
  };
```

Inputs configuration using useState I pass as props to my custom Input Component

```
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    username: {
      config: {
        type: "text",
        placeholder: "John Doe",
        id: "username",
        value: "",
        onChange: changeHandler.bind(this,inputs,setInputs,cloneDeep)
      },
      label: {
        label: "Username *",
        htmlFor: "username",
      },
    },
    email: {
      config: {
        type: "email",
        placeholder: "johndoe@example.com",
        id: "email2",
        value: "",
        onChange: (e) => {
          changeHandler(inputs, setInputs, cloneDeep,e);
        },
      },
      label: {
        label: "E-mail *",
        htmlFor: "email2",
      },
    },
  });
```

Edit: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use `event.persist()`.

Using `event.persist()` solved the problem but I wonder is it okay to use it?

Comment: Something like this my help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413135/how-can-i-have-only-one-onchange-for-several-inputs-in-reacthooks/64413319#64413319](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413135/how-can-i-have-only-one-onchange-for-several-inputs-in-reacthooks/64413319#64413319)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it using `event.persist()` which prevents the nullification of the original event, that's why  second time when the event was fired I was getting the error about trying to access property of null